# building llvm/clang 3.6 on windows 7 with mingw64

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, llvm-clang, mingw-w64

I pulled the latest svn repositories and did manage to build the same code with Visual Studio.  But I'm trying to use the YouCompleteMe plugin for vim, which needs clang built with mingw64.  The Visual Studio build did not work.  Here is the error.  Not really sure how to continue.

```
llvm[4]: Compiling Action.cpp for Release+Asserts build
llvm[4]: Compiling Compilation.cpp for Release+Asserts build
llvm[4]: Compiling CrossWindowsToolChain.cpp for Release+Asserts build
llvm[4]: Compiling Driver.cpp for Release+Asserts build
llvm[4]: Compiling DriverOptions.cpp for Release+Asserts build
llvm[4]: Compiling Job.cpp for Release+Asserts build
llvm[4]: Compiling MSVCToolChain.cpp for Release+Asserts build
In file included from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winnt.h:7681:0,
                 from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\minwindef.h:146,
                 from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windef.h:8,
                 from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windows.h:69,
                 from c:/llvm-3.6/tools/clang/lib/Driver/MSVCToolChain.cpp:38:
c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ktmtypes.h:88:9: error: declaration of 'UO
W _TRANSACTION_NOTIFICATION_RECOVERY_ARGUMENT::UOW' [-fpermissive]
     UOW UOW;
         ^
c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ktmtypes.h:13:16: error: changes meaning o
f 'UOW' from 'typedef GUID UOW' [-fpermissive]
   typedef GUID UOW,*PUOW;
                ^
In file included from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winnt.h:7681:0,
                 from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\minwindef.h:146,
                 from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windef.h:8,
                 from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windows.h:69,
                 from c:/llvm-3.6/tools/clang/lib/Driver/MSVCToolChain.cpp:38:
c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ktmtypes.h:132:9: error: declaration of 'U
OW _KCRM_TRANSACTION_BLOB::UOW' [-fpermissive]
     UOW UOW;
         ^
In file included from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winnt.h:7681:0,
                 from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\minwindef.h:146,
                 from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windef.h:8,
                 from c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windows.h:69,
                 from c:/llvm-3.6/tools/clang/lib/Driver/MSVCToolChain.cpp:38:
c:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ktmtypes.h:13:16: error: changes meaning o
f 'UOW' from 'typedef GUID UOW' [-fpermissive]
   typedef GUID UOW,*PUOW;
                ^
/usr/bin/rm: cannot lstat `/c/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Driver/Release+Asserts/MSVCTo
olChain.d.tmp': No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [/c/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Driver/Release+Asserts/MSVCToolChain.o] Er
ror 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/c/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Driver'
make[3]: *** [Driver/.makeall] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/llvm/tools/clang/lib'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/llvm/tools/clang'
make[1]: *** [clang/.makeall] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/llvm/tools'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing MSVC toolchain though this is inside mingw. Can you double check you ran cmake with the Unix Makefiles generator and that you didn't try to build inside a directory configure for msvc

Comment: I did.  It took me a while to figure that part out too.  But I'm using the MSYS shell with /mingw mounted to /mingw_64 in the MSYS config file.